# Identify windows in AutoHotkey like AutoIt

Tags: windows, window, autohotkey

In AutoIt one can identify a window by *both* its title and class. For example, to wait 10 seconds for a window to become active:

```
WinWaitActive("[TITLE:My Window; CLASS:My Class", "", 10)
```

Can I specify the name of the executable too? What is the equivalent in AutoHotkey? With title only, it would be:

```
WinWaitActive, My Window
```

and, with class only, it would be:

```
WinWaitActive, My Window, ahk_class My Class
```

Also, there is a `ahk_exe Process Name` criterion for the executable names.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the [docs](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/WinTitle.htm#multi), you can use multiple criteria.

```
WinWaitActive, My Window ahk_class MyClass ahk_exe ProcessName, , 10
```

Just make sure to specify the title first and have exactly one space between the different parts.